# How to make that setState work correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code.There is a floatingActionButton which have SpeedDial.I have two buttons in SpeedDial.
However I have only with delete button.I want that when I click it Text notes it change color.I tried to use setState but it dont work correctly.I dont know why my programm work in this way because all classes are stateful.I tried to check it with printing in console.I console it write that i want but it dont work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';
import 'package:notev2/scr/func.dart';
import 'colors.dart';
import 'variables.dart';
import 'newnote.dart';

class homepage extends StatefulWidget {
 const homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _homepageState createState() => _homepageState();
}

class _homepageState extends State<homepage> {
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: new AppBar(
       toolbarHeight: 0.0,
     ),
     backgroundColor: dark,
     body: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         Row(
           children: <Widget>[
             //надпись заметки
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35),
               child: Text(
                 "Notes",
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 72,
                   color: delmode==0?grey:coral,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             Container(
               child: Text(
                 "Never Settle",
                 style: TextStyle(color: grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               width: 10,
             ), // лупа
             Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
               child: IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
                 color: coral,
                 iconSize: 30,
                 onPressed: () {},
               ),
             ),
             Container(
               child: IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                 color: coral,
                 iconSize: 30,
                 onPressed: () {},
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
         Expanded(
           child: Expanded(
             child: ListView.builder(
               itemCount: data.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                 return GestureDetector(
                   child: Container(
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border.all(
                         color: grey,
                         width: 1,
                       ),
                     ),
                     height: 50,
                     child: Center(
                       child: Text(
                         data[index]['title'],
                         style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 35,
                           color: grey,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   onTap: () {
                     //print(index.toString() + " is taped");
                     buff = index;
                     shower(index, data, tContr, dContr);
                     Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'watchpage');
                   },
                 );
                 /*ListTile(
                   title:Text(tList[index]),
                 );*/
               },
             ),
           ),
         ),
         Spacer(),
       ],
     ),
     floatingActionButton:
         /*FloatingActionButton(
       backgroundColor: dark,
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           side: BorderSide(
               color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 103, 104, 1),
               width: 2,
               style: BorderStyle.solid),
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
       onPressed: () {
         buff = data.length + 1;
         Navigator.pushNamed(context, "newnote");
       },
       child: Icon(
         Icons.add,
         color: coral,
       ),
     ),*/
         _getFAB(),
   );
 }

 Widget _getFAB() {
   return SpeedDial(
     overlayOpacity: 0.0,
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         side: BorderSide(color: grey, width: 2, style: BorderStyle.solid),
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
     animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
     animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
       size: 22,
     ),
     backgroundColor: light,
     visible: true,
     curve: Curves.bounceIn,
     children: [
       // FAB 1
       SpeedDialChild(
           child: Icon(Icons.add),
           backgroundColor: light,
           onTap: () {
             buff = data.length + 1;
             Navigator.pushNamed(context, "newnote");
           },
           label: 'Button 1',
           labelStyle: TextStyle(
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
               color: Colors.white,
               fontSize: 16.0),
           labelBackgroundColor: light),
       // FAB 2
       SpeedDialChild(
           child: Icon(Icons.delete),
           backgroundColor: light,
           onTap: () {
             setState(() {
               print("delmode" + delmode.toString());
               delmode = !delmode;
             });
           },
           label: 'Button 2',
           labelStyle: TextStyle(
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
               color: Colors.white,
               fontSize: 16.0),
           labelBackgroundColor: light)
     ],
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use delmode as boolean? Why you need to convert to string before? And i'm not sure that !delmode is working with String.

Comment: I don't think so.I change it only when I print result in console.When I change value in program delmode is boolean

Comment: i never used this one to compare boolean delmode==0?grey:coral . What's happen if you change to this? delmode ? grey : coral